# Ruby regex: extract text between quotes

Tags: ruby, regex

What is the best way to get quoted words / phrases out of the text?

This my attempt does not work properly:

```
text.scan(/\"([^"]+)/)
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I think you want:

```
text.scan(/"([^"]*)"/)
```

It works in [Rubular](http://www.rubular.com/r/E5v30dehud).

Comment: Note that double-quotes have no special meaning in a regular expression. That can more simply be: `/"([^"]*)"/`

Comment: @Phrogz, that's what I thought.  Thanks for clarifying.